EOF во время ввода. Syntax Error
При выполнении кода на локальном компьютере всё в порядке, но при отправке в проверяющую систему выводит такую ошибку
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 4, in <module>
    n, m = list(map(int, input().split()))
  File "<string>", line 1
    4 4
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing


Проблема решена. Оказывается я выбрал версию Python 2.7 в системе‍♂️

Поясню: в питоне 2 input исполняет код, то есть если пользователь ввел 1+2 то функция возвращает 3. А если пользователь вводит не код, то получается ошибка.
